# How to change a fields label name based on another fields value?

Tags: entities

I have a content type and it has two fields:

- Field One (select list)
- Field Two (text area)

What I want to do is to change Field Two's label name based on Field One's value in node add/edit page and node dipslay. If `Option 1` selected in Field One field, then make the Field Two's label name **Option 1** etc.

[image]

**How can I do this?**

Comment: You can go for jQuery to update the second field label with the value of first field option.

Comment: I keep wondering where you get the inspiration from about all such kind of special questions you keep coming up with ... Anyway, how many possible values ("option 1" being one of them) does your "Field One" have, only a few (say between 2 and 10 or so), or dozens (if not hundreds, which would be a nightmare of course if it would be implemented as a select list, instead of an auto complete)?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, I'm creating web bibliographies based on Drupal Framework (in different academic domains). I've already created 4 ones. Each of them have some similarities and some differences. Most of the questions I asked are coming from these stuff. :) // Yes, there are only 6 options. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery is the way to do go.

Since when you edit nodes it uses the admin theme (seven), we need to add the jQuery to the admin theme (seven).

> **Note:** The default **admin theme** for Drupal 7 is "Seven", if you have changed your admin theme, then just edit that theme instead.

Go to the folder `drupal/themes/seven` and edit **seven.info**

After `stylesheets[screen][] = style.css` add the following line

```
scripts[] = cool.js
```

Create cool.js inside the seven folder (path would be `drupal/themes/seven/cool.js`)

#### cool.js

```
(function ($) {

   (function Forever(){ // we create a function called Forever

   var grabselectedtext = $('#edit-field-test-und option:checked').text();

     $('label').each(function(){
      if ($(this).attr('for') == 'edit-body-und-0-value') {
  
         if (grabselectedtext != '- None -') {
           $(this).text(grabselectedtext);
         } else {
             $(this).text('Field Two');
           }
         }   

     });   

   setTimeout(Forever, 1);

   })();

})(jQuery);
```

In this example the select list field is named `test` and the field to change label is the `body` field.

---

The above does exactly what you asked, but perhaps it might be even better (depending on your use case) if you hide the `body` field if the `test` field is equal to None. Then if the person selects something the body field reveals itself by sliding down.

#### cool.js (option 2)

```
(function ($) {


  (function Forever(){ // we create a function called Forever

    var grabselectedtext = $('#edit-field-test-und option:checked').text();
    $('label').each(function(){
       if ($(this).attr('for') == 'edit-body-und-0-value') {
  
         if (grabselectedtext != '- None -') {
         $(this).text(grabselectedtext);
         $('#body-add-more-wrapper').slideDown(2000); // slides down in 2 seconds     
         } else {
           $(this).text('Field Two');
           $('#body-add-more-wrapper').slideUp(2000); // slides up in 2 seconds
          }
     }   

    });   

  setTimeout(Forever, 1); 

  })();

})(jQuery);
```

Then add this CSS to Seven's **style.css**

```
#body-add-more-wrapper { display: none; }
```

> **PS:** Not a good idea to use the body field for this, better create your own custom field, otherwise all body fields will be hidden. I
> didn't because I was lazy as this is just for example purposes.

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: I've not experimented with this (yet), but assuming this works I'd say "*Waw!*". What isn't clear to me however is its relationship with the Seven theme: does this only workk for Seven? What if I'd use another theme? Can you add some more details about that in your answer?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens updated answer. It will work with any admin theme.

Comment: Aha, that makes more sense! And looking at the screenprint you added to the end, this seems pretty close (identical?) to what @herci asked for. Chapeau!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens According to [Google translate](https://www.google.ca/search?q=translate+Chapeau&oq=translate+Chapeau&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.1935j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  Chapeau = Hat ??? (O_o)

Comment: you're close: heads of (= I'm impressed). Ps: sorry I forgot one is only allowed to use English on this site ... if I remember correctly the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) (oeps: rules).

Comment: @NoSssweat, thanks a lot. This is exactly what I need. I had tried a similar method but the JS structure I used was not correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module. Excerpt from its project page:

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.
>
> When editing a node (or any other entity type that supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are dynamically modified with the States API.
>
> You can, for example, define a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser" checkbox is checked.

So if you have like 6 possible values (Option 1, ... Option 6), as in your comment below the question, you could create 6 fields with label "Option 1", ..., "Option 6".

Not sure if it is acceptable to "split" your "Field Two" in like 6 separated fields, but at least it would change the field labels as you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using the Conditional Fields but I couldn't split the field two, unfortunately.

Comment: grrrrrrrrrrrr, that ruins the party, right? I suggest you somehow add that to your question. But I hope you don't mind I don't give up yet ... Can you (briefly) explain why you cannot split that fields two? Like what kind of other things would break (or would become unacceptable)? That might give me other inspiration for an alternative approach.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. Because I use this field (second one) in Search API, with other dependencies etc. Hımm, maybe I will split this field and try to arrange each feature (search etc.) separately. But if I find a easy solution without needing separation of fields I will use it :)

Comment: Hm, then I have another variation: keep your existing "Field Two" but make it invisible for the user (using some type of theming-technique), but use it to actually "store" the actual value specified in only 1 of those 6 extra fields. There may be multiple solutions to store that Field Two value, but for sure using Rules (event: before saving content, with action "set data value", etc) would work. What do you think, worth adding to my answer?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens checkout my answer, I believe it's the better approach.