# use conditional fields to change a label on a field

Tags: 8, entities

Is it possible to change the label on a field using the conditional fields module.  What I want is to call a field "Effective Date" in one case and "Published Date" in another but have it be the same field.

is that possible with the conditional fields module or any other module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this similar D7 question [How to change a fields label name based on another fields value?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197631/how-to-change-a-fields-label-name-based-on-another-fields-value)

```
(function ($) {

   (function Forever(){ // we create a function called Forever

   var grabselectedtext = $('#edit-field-test-und option:checked').text();
   // this grabs the text of the field you want to depend on.

     $('label').each(function(){
      if ($(this).attr('for') == 'edit-body-und-0-value') {

         if (grabselectedtext != '- None -') {
           $(this).text(grabselectedtext);
         } else {
             $(this).text('Field Two');
           }
         }   

     });   

   setTimeout(Forever, 1);

   })();

})(jQuery);
```

You want to attach this JS code to a library. Then attach the library via a hook_form_alter and check for form ID and content type.